# history on redux state is not availb but it is available on react component

Tags: reactjs, react-router, redux, react-redux, react-router-redux

My `index.js` looks like:

```
const store = configureStore()

render(
    <Root history={history} store={store} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

and my `Root.js` looks like:

```
class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    const { store } = this.props

    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
          <ReduxRouter />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

Root.propTypes = {
  store: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.object
}

export default Root
```

and my `configureStore.js` is like:

```
export default function configureStore() {

  let createStoreWithMiddleware = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    reduxReactRouter({ routes, createHistory })
    )(createStore)

  const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(rootReducer)

  return store
```

`routes.js`:

```
const routes =  (
    <Router>
        <Route path={"/"} component={LoginView}>
        <Route path={"/login"} component={DashboardView} />
        </Route>
  </Router>
)

export default routes
```

and my `LoginView` component is like:

```
class LoginView extends Component {

    componentDidMount(){
        const {actions} = this.props
        actions.login()
    }

    render() {
        console.log("printing props")
        console.log(this.props)
        console.log(this.props.history)
        return (
            <div>
                <Login />
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default LoginView


function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        login: state.login
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    actions: bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch)
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LoginView)
```

I am very confused relating to `history`. 
In my component I am getting `history` in props. Like `this.props.history` as I have done `console.log(this.props.history)` in component.

But in my `actions` I can not get `history` any way..

My actions is like:

```
export function login(){

    return (dispatch, getState, history) => {
        console.log("get state")
        console.log(getState())
        console.log("history")
        console.log(history)
        var message = "hellooww world"
        return { message, type: loginTypes.LOGIN }
    }
}
```

Here I can get `getState()` but not `history`.

What If I want to `redirect`? I want `history` so that I can redirect it like:

`history.pushState(null, '/dashboard')`

Can anyone help me.. ? Really confused on this..

Answer (score 0):

Well I found this GitHub page offering a simple way of transitioning from an action, maybe it will help (it has an example of a login action):

https://github.com/johanneslumpe/redux-history-transitions